# Trigger a function when a button is clicked, using a directive. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function inside my directive called "myFunction ()", on the other hand in the template, I have a button. I want when you click on the button to run the function, BUT IT IS IMPORTANT, DO NOT USE a ng-click, to call this function. It may sound weird, but I have my reasons, so I need to do it this way. Maybe assigning a class to the button, something like this, but INSIDE OF THE DIRECTIVE, without using the controler.

```
    app.directive('validate', function ($timeout) {

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: 'ngModel', 

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
              if (!ngModel){
                return;          
              }

              scope.directive_function= function(){

              }

              ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){

              })

              function myFunction= function(){
                alert("clicked");
              }

           }


        };
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v9wvjavz/

Comment: Please explain your actual problem. This isn't a site for people to solve arbitrary coding puzzles. If there's a good reason why ng-click absolutely cannot be used, it's worth including in the question.

Comment: `ng-click` is a directive, so whatever your "good reasons" for not using `ng-click` are, making a new directive to do the same task as another directive *rarely makes sense*.

Comment: look the answer of sachila ranawaka is more or less i  needed

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why don't you use ng-click in the first place. it's angular build in directive and it's perfectly ok to use in a directive

But since you need an alternative way , use `element.bind` to trigger the click events

```
element.bind('click', function() {
   alert("click")
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v9wvjavz/3/)

Comment: remove the require ngModel from the directive since the button don't have a ng model directive

Comment: This is more or less what I need. But if I have a text field, the function will also be executed. How do I make it active only when a button is clicked.

Comment: create a flag to check whether element click happen on input or button. then based on the call the function